# Android Studio and Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio, compatibility

All the people that I work with use Eclipse for creating android apps. However, I recently found out that Android is no longer supporting Eclipse and they are moving to Android Studio. All that apps that I am working on have been complied and created with Eclipse.

I'm thinking if the code and the programming language is the same, then the compiler or the IDE shouldn't matter. Would we be able to still work together and share code if I switched to Android Studio and they stayed in Eclipse? What are some of the potential problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already stated, everybody would have to make the switch to Android Studio at the same time, and you would need to make some changes to the build system.

Until everyone makes the switch, you should just use the Eclipse/ADT bundle.

You can technically keep the same old folder structure for source files when porting a project to Android Studio (we tried it, it works), but the different build system is the main change that throws a wrench into the works.

Eclipse uses the ANT build system for Android projects.

Android Studio uses the Gradle build system.

We are in the process of planning a switch at my work, and everybody will need to switch at the same time, and the build system will have to be ported from ANT over to Gradle.

See more about Gradle: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide

Migrating old projects to Android Studio: http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html

*edited for clarity regarding folder structure

Comment: Thank you @Daniel Nugent! I wanted to move on to android studio, but you have cleared up a lot of things for me!

Answer (score 1):

No, the two IDEs use different project structures, but Android Studio has a very nice wizard that allows you to move your Eclipse project to AS. I really recommend you and your team to move to AS.

Comment: I agree completely with this. You must move all at the very same time, or not at all.

Comment: Well in that case I'll have to stick with Eclipse until they move on, I am the new guy here. But thank you for information!